# Setting Proxy Username & password using Objective-C - iPhone

Tags: ios

I'm testing an application in iPhone simulator where it actually makes an HTTP request using `dataWithContentsOfURL:` method of `NSData`.

My mac has proxy settings protected with username & password. By default the simulator is not considering the proxy settings provided in my Mac. I'm getting the following response. Is there a way where we can programmatically provide the proxy username, password so that the simulator can read the values and allow the request to take place.

**Response:**

```
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<FONT face="Helvetica">
<big><strong></strong></big><BR>
</FONT>
<blockquote>
<TABLE border=0 cellPadding=1 width="80%">
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica">
<big>Access Denied (authentication_failed)</big>
<BR>
<BR>
</FONT>
</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica">
Your credentials could not be authenticated: "Credentials are missing.". You will not be permitted access until your credentials can be verified.
</FONT>
</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica">
This is typically caused by an incorrect username and/or password, but could also be caused by network problems.
</FONT>
</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica" SIZE=2>
<BR>
For assistance, contact your network support team.
</FONT>
</TD></TR>
</TABLE>
</blockquote>
</FONT>
</BODY></HTML>
```

Thanks 
Sudheer

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge{

    if ([challenge previousFailureCount] == 0) {
        NSURLCredential *newCredential;
        newCredential=[NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:@"ABC"
                                                 password:@"ABC"
                                              persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceNone];
        [[challenge sender] useCredential:newCredential
               forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
          } else {

        [[challenge sender] cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        // inform the user that the user name and password
        // in the preferences are incorrect
    }

}
```