# iOS stringWithContentsOfURL gives HTML error

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios6

I am trying to Parse Google Maps api with `SBJSon` but before parsing when I use the below code gives me the `Access Denied` errors in the HTML this error comes only when I run on the `Device` and If I run the same in the simulator ..it gives me the google maps api string..what should be the error for Device running.

```
NSString *String = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url
                                                    encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                       error:nil];

NSLog(@"string %@",string);
```

error

`<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE>
</HEAD>....`

full Html error is similar  of 
[Setting Proxy Username & password using Objective-C - iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510730/setting-proxy-username-password-using-objective-c-iphone)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The network your device is connected to does not allow access to the URL. Since you are able to access the URL from your MAC, connect your device to the same network as your MAC. It should work.

Alternate solution, first access some URL from the device Safari browser. If asked for authentication, provide correct username and password. Once connected, do not close the tab or Safari app. Run your application and the URL should now work.

---

**EDIT**

If you still face authentication problem, may be you are better off implementing asynchronous downloader which implements [`NSURLConnectionDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSURLConnectionDelegate/connection%3adidReceiveAuthenticationChallenge%3a). Provide the authentication parameters in method,

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge;
```

The API you are using `stringWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:` will not give you much flexibility.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I am connected to the same network for MAC and Device and If i open my google api url in device browser it display the json file

Comment: Thanks for all your help.I used the Nsurlconnection delegate but this method didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge is not been getting called ..

Comment: @user2519391 You sure you have implemented the downloader correctly? Because it should definitely work, if properly implemented.

Comment: Sorry for late reply.. I was trying to use asynchronous download instead stringWithContentsofURl ,that also gives me the access denied .. now to call urs didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge...I am using....  [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

Comment: isnt sufficient to use this delegate method to call this didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge method

Comment: Calling the URL with `NSURLConnection` and implementing `didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge` should give you a better idea.  `didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge` will get called if your proxy requires authentication.